# How to get closer to object in Unity 3D VR Scenes?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, system, solar

I'm making a VR Application in Unity3D. A Solar System and imported GoogleVR SDK.Ctrl and Alt functions are working.Head moving and neck moving. But i want to get closer to my objects (near to the sun and planets) Zoom in Or Zoom out. How i can do this ?

Comment: You are most certainly using [tag:c#], not [tag:unityscript].

Answer (score 0):

You should look at googles [dev portal](https://developers.google.com/vr/elements/overview) under locomotion. They list a few movement options that are used in many applications and integrated in their sdk.